# Update on "Add Store Code to URLs" Setting and URL Redirection

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, multistore, url-rewrite, store-switcher

Recently, I made the Magento settings update regarding the "Add Store Code to URLs." I have set this option to "No," which has successfully removed the store code from the URLs.

However, I have encountered a new issue. Customers are still able to access the old URLs, which now result in a 404 error. I would like to explore the possibility of redirecting these old URLs to the default URL instead.

Is there a way to implement automatic redirection for the old URLs? This would ensure a seamless transition for customers and prevent them from encountering 404 errors. I would greatly appreciate your guidance and assistance in resolving this matter.

Eg:-

https://website.com/se/website-silver.html should redirect to https://website.com/website-silver.html

Thank you for your attention to this issue. I look forward to your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add this in .htaccess for apache

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^se/(.*)$ $1
```

or this for nginx

```
rewrite ^/se/(.*)$ $1 last;
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add a `/` after the "se" to the nginx rewrite, to avoid urls begining with "se" from being redirected ? Like "/sea-products.html" would be redirected to "/a-products.html". The fix would be `rewrite ^/se/(.*)$ $1 last;`

Comment: right. thanks for the heads up

Comment: Yes its correct but don't know why it was not working on our server, but worked with little different settings, anyway thanks for providing the solution

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was worked with the following code on Apache

RewriteRule ^se$ https://website.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^se/(.*)$ https://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]